# Linux NFS client: stat causes ongoing readdirplus iteration to restart to earlier cookie

Tags: linux-kernel, nfs

Scenario:

1. Linux NFS client iterates a directory with many (millions) of files, e.g. via `getdents()` until all entries are done. In my case, `READDIRPLUS` is being used under the hood.
2. At the same time, run the `stat` tool on a file inside that directory.

The directory on the server is not being modified anywhere (on this client or any other client).

Result: the next `getdents` will get stuck for a long time, it appears to be re-iterating some of the work it already did, by going back to a previous NFS `READDIRPLUS` cookie.

Why does the `stat` command cause this?

(I assume `stat` requires the path name to be resolved to an inode/dentry, but not sure how it affects the ongoing directory iteration)

The problem doesn't appear to happen if the dir iteration is using `READDIR` and not `READDIRPLUS`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in the kernel handling of invalid cache entries when READDIRPLUS is being used. An initial patch is given here: https://marc.info/?l=linux-nfs&m=156336530903066&w=4